# Integrating bootstrap & Typeplate

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I would like to use Twitter bootstrap as front end framework and Typeplate for typography.

The respective framework can be downloaded from below URLs and are free to use.

http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/
http://typeplate.com/

CSS classes for few of the HTML elements are defined in both frameworks (E.g, HTML,body,h1)

I ran Firebug on Typeplate site and saw the value of computed fields for font-family and font-size etc...
Even when I use the same values in my site for css(even after removing the bootstrap css), I am not able to get the typography of typeplate.

I am using typeplate after twitter bootstrap.

Please advise.

Basically I would like to consolidate the properties applied to the text "The Happy Prince" in the below code

```
<html class="no-js wf-ffmetaserifwebpro-i7-active wf-ffmetaserifwebpro-i5-active wf-ffmetaserifwebpro-n5-active wf-ffmetaserifwebpro-n7-active wf-active">
<head><style>
article, aside, details, figcaption, figure, footer, header, hgroup, main, nav, section, summary
{
    display: block;
}
html
{
    font-family: sans-serif;
    -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;
}
body
{
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-right: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    margin-left: 0px;
}
h1
{
    font-size: 2em;
    margin-top: 0.67em;
    margin-right: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 0.67em;
    margin-left: 0px;
}
html
{
    line-height: 1.65;
    font-family: serif;
    font-size: 112.5%;
    font-style: normal;
    font-variant: normal;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-size-adjust: none;
    font-stretch: normal;
}
body
{
    color: #444444;
    word-wrap: break-word;
}
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6
{
    line-height: 1;
    margin-top: 0px;
}
h1, .alpha
{
    font-size: 3.33rem;
    margin-bottom: 0.49rem;
}
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6
{
    color: #222222;
}
body
{
    margin-top: 6em;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-bottom: 6em;
    margin-left: auto;
    max-width: 34em;
    background-image: url("../img/subtle_grunge.png");
    background-attachment: scroll;
    background-repeat: repeat;
    background-position-x: left;
    background-position-y: top;
    background-size: auto;
    background-origin: padding-box;
    background-clip: border-box;
    background-color: transparent;
}
.wf-active body, .wf-inactive body
{
    font-family: "ff-meta-serif-web-pro",serif;
    font-weight: 400;
    visibility: visible;
}

</style></head>
<body><section><article><header>

<h1>
 The Happy Prince
</h1>

</header></article></section></body></html>
```

"

Comment: Are you using typeplate **after** bootstrap? Could you put an example in JSFiddle or similar?

Answer (score 0):

if i were you, i'd try to use custom build of bootstrap framework, excluded '**Normalize and reset**', '**Body type and links**' and '**Headings, body, etc**'.

Comment: I'm the main dev for Typeplate. I agree with Evgeniy's answer above. Probably better to go with a custom build of Bootstrap and avoid using their typography defaults. If you need further assistance feel free to open an issue on our repo's issue tracker and I'll come to the rescue :) https://github.com/typeplate/typeplate.github.io/issues